# limit of a recurrent serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to find to determine the limit for $u_n$ which I determined that it's a decreasing series and that $v_n$ is an increasing one.

let $a >0$  And  $b>0$  .

> $u_0=a And v_0=b$

$u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n+v_n}{2}$  and   $v_{n+1}=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{u_n}+\frac{1}{v_n}}$

Comment: Hint 1) $u_{n+1}v_{n+1} = u_nv_n$. 2)  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (u_n - v_n ) = 0$. From this, you can deduce the limit is the GM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding
 achille hui's comment.

$\begin{array}\\
u_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{u_n+v_n}{2},\\
v_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{2}{\frac{1}{u_n}+\frac{1}{v_n}}\\
&=\dfrac{2u_nv_n}{u_n+v_n}\\
&=\dfrac{2u_nv_n}{2u_{n+1}}\\
u_{n+1}v_{n+1}
&=u_nv_n\\
v_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{u_nv_n}{u_{n+1}}\\
u_1, v_1
&=a, b\\
u_1v_1
&=ab\\
&=u_nv_n\\
v_n
&=\dfrac{ab}{u_n}\\
u_{n+1}-v_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{u_n+v_n}{2}-\dfrac{ab}{u_{n+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{u_n+v_n}{2}-\dfrac{2ab}{u_{n}+v_n}\\
&=\dfrac{(u_n+v_n)^2-4ab}{2(u_{n}+v_n)}\\
&=\dfrac{(u_n-v_n)^2}{2(u_{n}+v_n)}\\
&=\dfrac{u_n-v_n}{2}\dfrac{u_n-v_n}{u_{n}+v_n}\\
|u_{n+1}-v_{n+1}|
&=|\dfrac{u_n-v_n}{2}||\dfrac{u_n-v_n}{u_{n}+v_n}|\\
&<|\dfrac{u_n-v_n}{2}|\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$u_n, v_n
\to \sqrt{ab}
$.

Comment: Got it , all what I need was digging deeper to get the limit.   
$Thanks $